# Write Visual Studio for Mac license type in Console

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I need a bash command to write Visual Studio for Mac current active licence (Community, Professional or Enterprise).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called **`vstool.exe`** that can provide the account info on macOS by passing it the parameters of **`account info`**.

```
mono /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/vstool.exe account info

Xamarin Account Tool
Account:
    XXXXXX <XXXXX@XXXXX.com>

Checking licenses...

Licenses:
    Xamarin.Android: Visual Studio XXXXXXXX
    Xamarin.iOS: Visual Studio XXXXXXXX
    Xamarin.Mac: Visual Studio XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working for me. I have already Enterprise activated and the command output is: Xamarin Account Tool Not logged in

Comment: @AnasELHAJJAJI Then login, `vstool.exe account login`

Comment: the login not working as well: Xamarin.Components.Ide.Accounts.AccountService+LoginException: Invalid username or password.

Comment: But when I open Visual Studio for Mac, it shows me Enterprise edition. Is there any offline tool?